# The given key was not present in the dictionary in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, text-files

I'm getting this error in vb.net, when trying to connect to mysql database:

```
An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
```

I'm reading the database information (user, password, host, database) from a textfile.

```
 Dim FILE_NAME As String = "D:\connection.txt"

    Dim objReader As New StreamReader(FILE_NAME)


    Public Sub textfileopener()
        host = objReader.ReadLine
        user = objReader.ReadLine
        password = objReader.ReadLine
        database = objReader.ReadLine

        objReader.Close()
    End Sub
```

Then assigning it to these variables:

```
Public host 
Public database  
Public user  
Public password
```

Then finally I connect to the database:

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=" + host + ";Database=" + database + ";Uid=" + user + ";Pwd=" + password + ";")
```

I think its not getting any values. Because if I assign values right ahead, I can connect without problems:

```
    Public host = "localhost"
    Public database = "db"
    Public user = "root"
    Public password = "pw
```

But if I do it this way then it will all be constant. And I cannot change anything at all.
My problem is getting the correct values into the connection string. How do I do that?

**Update**

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
  Message="An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: The given key was not present in the dictionary."
  Source="QueryGenerator"
  StackTrace:
       at QueryGenerator.My.MyProject.MyForms.Create__Instance__[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
       at QueryGenerator.My.MyProject.MyForms.get_Form1()
       at QueryGenerator.My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Users\Nrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at QueryGenerator.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
       Message="The given key was not present in the dictionary."
       Source="mscorlib"
       StackTrace:
            at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
            at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_UserID()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
            at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
            at QueryGenerator.connection..ctor() in C:\Users\Nrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator\connection.vb:line 22
            at QueryGenerator.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\Nrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\QueryGenerator\QueryGenerator\Form1.vb:line 5
       InnerException:
```

Comment: The code you have shown does not access a Dictionary and can not have thrown the exception.  The exception stack trace will give you the exact location of the error.  Please post that code.

Comment: have you solve this?, i got the same error when connecting to local db (mysql 8 on win 10-64bit), but when i change databse that hosted on win 7-64bit mysql 5.6, everythings fine... help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is coming from the MySQL client. It appears that it's expecting you to provide a particular parameter in the connection string that you are not. While I'm not familiar enough with the managed MySQL driver to tell you what's missing, the fact that something *is* missing is pretty clear.

You may want to try adding a space between the semicolon that signals the end of one parameter and the name of the next parameter. Like this:

```
Dim con As New MySqlConnection("Server=" + host + "; Database=" + database + "; Uid=" + user + "; Pwd=" + password + ";")
```