# c# Mysql Connect: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: c#, mysql, dictionary

I've got a problem with my new c# project. There's the following Exception: `The given key was not present in the dictionary`. I've got a database and a empty data table.
I've written the following code:

```
using System.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace ConnectingToMySqlDB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        MySqlConnection conn;
        string connString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InizialiteComponent();
        }

        private void bntSendData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connString = "SERVER=db4free.net;PORT=3306;DATABASE=namedb;UID=username;PWD=pass;";
            try
            {
                conn = new MySqlConnection();
                conn.ConnectionString = connString;
                conn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
        }
    }
}
```

where's the mistake? why doesn't it work?

Comment: Have you seen this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616677/the-given-key-was-not-present-in-the-dictionary-in-vb-net

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596605/unity-c-sharp-application-keynotfoundexception

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. this is not the solution